# How to configure my Xbox 360 to *always* use the hard drive for saving

Tags: xbox-360

I find it annoying that I have to select my hard drive every single time I fire up a game when it asks me where to save (and load) games to (and from).

Is there a way to preconfigure that I don't want to select it every single time and set the hard drive to default?

Globally would be fine, but it would be okay to do that on a per profile / per game basis too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just got the answer from Xbox support chat:

> 1. From the Xbox Dashboard, go to Settings, and then select System.
> 2. Select Storage, and then select your primary storage device.
> 3. Select System Items, and then select Cloud Storage Console Copy.
> 4. Select Delete.
>      You will be asked to confirm that you want your saved games to remain in the cloud, 
>      and future updates to your saved games will not be synced with this console.

This stops the pop-up.

Comment: This will only stop the prompt if the only storage device on the console is the hard drive. If a USB drive is attached, games will still prompt which device to use.

Comment: Thanks Adeese for this addition. For my ususal use case (no usb attached) this is totally sufficient though :)

Comment: I had nothing called `Cloud Storage Console Copy` in my `System Items` list. This is probably because I wasn't actually using my cloud storage. Instead I deleted my `Cloud Content Cache`, which allowed me to disable my cloud storage as described by @Alaa Adly.

Comment: I have cloud storage disabled, only have the hard drive, no other devices.  Games still prompt for this information (even though there is only one choice!!) every time I launch them...

Answer (score 5):

No, there's no global setting for this. Individual games can store the location of your saved game, so they don't prompt you, but as you've seen, most games will ask you every time you play.

There is [a thread on Microsoft's forums](http://forums.xbox.com/xbox_forums/general_discussion/f/133/p/10325/164767.aspx), in their wish list section, asking to have this implemented, but I have no idea if that carries any weight with them, and it's possible that even if they did add that option, it might not be retroactive: it's possible that game developers would have to update their games to read your setting and use it properly.

Answer (score 2):

You Can Simply Go To System Settings , Then Go to storage highlight your cloud storage , Press Y on your controller , select disable

Comment: My Xbox wouldn't allow me to disable `Cloud Saved Games`, saying that I had items there even though it was empty. I had to go into `Hard Drive` > `System Items` and delete my `Cloud Content Cache` before I was able to disable it.